# Assigning values to an empty adjacency matrix based on matching column values

Tags: r

I have an nxn dataset, say 5X5 data set.

```
ALPHA   BETA    GAMMA   DELTA   EPSILON
A       B       A       X       1
B       C       3       X       3
C       D       E       Z       4
D       A       D       X       5
E       A       2       Z       2
```

I use column “ALPHA” to create an empty adjacency matrix (Aij),

```
    A   B   C   D   E
A   0   0   0   0   0
B   0   0   0   0   0
C   0   0   0   0   0
D   0   0   0   0   0
E   0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to reassign Adjacency matrix values to 1 or 0 based on the matched values of column “DELTA” such that, if “DELTA” matches we set Aij=1 and 0 otherwise. That is, we will have a new adjacency matrix that looks like the following,

```
    A   B   C   D   E
A   0   1   0   1   0
B   1   0   0   1   0
C   0   0   0   0   1
D   1   1   0   0   0
E   0   0   1   0   0
```

What loop command can or matching technique can I use to assign the new values?

Thanks.
Phil

Comment: I don't quite understand how you made your adjacency matrix. "ALPHA" was A B C D E; "DELTA" was X X Z X Z - so there are no letters in common, and yet the adjacency matrix has A21, A41, A42, A53 = 1 (as well as the symmetric values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop could work.  You have A(i=j) as 0 in your example so I subtracted a diagonal matrix

```
DELTA<-c("X","X","Z","X","Z")
Adj<-mat.or.vec(nr=length(DELTA), nc=length(DELTA))
for (i in 1:length(DELTA)){
    Adj[i,DELTA==DELTA[i]]<-1
}
Adj<-Adj-diag(length(DELTA))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outer`

```
 res <- +(outer(df1$DELTA, df1$DELTA, FUN='=='))*!diag(dim(df1)[1])
 dimnames(res) <- rep(list(df1$ALPHA),2)
 res
 #  A B C D E
 #A 0 1 0 1 0
 #B 1 0 0 1 0
 #C 0 0 0 0 1
 #D 1 1 0 0 0
 #E 0 0 1 0 0
```

Or

```
  sapply(df1$DELTA, `==`, df1$DELTA) - diag(dim(df1)[1])
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(ALPHA = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), BETA = c("B", 
 "C", "D", "A", "A"), GAMMA = c("A", "3", "E", "D", "2"), DELTA = c("X", 
 "X", "Z", "X", "Z"), EPSILON = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L)), .Names = c("ALPHA", 
 "BETA", "GAMMA", "DELTA", "EPSILON"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```